# How to loop and fill nested dict/json in python using Requests' specific response/output

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested, python-requests

I'm crawling a site and getting data from some ajax dropdowns, and the data is related.
So basically, for simplicity, let's say I crawl the 1st dropdown and it gives me, name and value, and I use the values to run a loop and for the next dropdown and get its name, value, etc. Let's say the data is for countries, then regions, then districts, etc.
So I can get the name, values; now I want to join each country to be filled with its related regions, and regions be filled with its related districts.

Sample Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://somesite.com/"

COUNTRIES = {
    "NAME": 1,
    "ANOTHER": 2
}

REGIONS = {}
DISTRICTS = {}

def fetch(s, url, value, store):
    data = {
        'id': str(value)
    }
    res = s.post(url, data=data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html5lib')
    options = soup.find_all('option')[1:]
    for option in options:
        name = option.text
        value = option.get('value')
        #value = option.attrs['value']
        store[name] = value

for name, val in COUNTRIES.items():
    fetch(requests, URL+"getregions", val, REGION)

for name, val in REGIONS.items():
    fetch(requests, URL+"getdistricts", val, DISTRICTS)
```

I want to combine all this in the end to have one nested json/dict of the form:

```
DATA = {
    "COUNTRY1": {
        "REGION1": {
            "DISTRICT1": { "WARDS": ..... },
            "DISTRICT2": { "WARDS": ..... },
        },
        "REGION2": {
            "DISTRICT1": { "WARDS": ..... },
            "DISTRICT2": { "WARDS": ..... },
        },
    },
    "COUNTRY2": {
        "REGION1": {
            "DISTRICT1": { "WARDS": ..... },
            "DISTRICT2": { "WARDS": ..... },
        },
        "REGION2": {
            "DISTRICT1": { "WARDS": ..... },
            "DISTRICT2": { "WARDS": ..... },
        },
    },
}
```

If possible also in this form:

```
[{
    country: "NAME",
    region: "RNAME",
    district: "DNAME",
    ward: "WNAME"
},
{
    country: "NAME",
    region: "RNAME",
    district: "DNAME",
    ward: "WNAME"
},
```

For both SQL and NoSQL.

I've thought of closures and such but I just can't seem to find the logic to implement it.
Anyone who can help will be really thankful, preferred answer in Python, please.

I'm new to asking questions here and it took me a while to compose this question, I apologize if it's not concise and please ask if you haven't understood so I can explain more.

Comment: Cant do a dict COUNTRIES with same key "COUNTRY1"